# 'SKNode?' does not have a member named 'position'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sknode

What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to figure this out. I have tried putting an **exclamation** mark behind: `var thisBlock = self.childNodeWithName(block)`,

this gives me a new error saying. `type () does not confirm to protocol 'BooleanType'.`

```
func blockRunner() {
        for(block, blockStatus) in self.blockStatuses {
            var thisBlock = self.childNodeWithName(block)
            if blockStatus.shouldRunBlock() {
                blockStatus.timeGapForNextRun = random()
                blockStatus.currentInterval = 0
                blockStatus.isRunning = true
            }

            if blockStatus.isRunning {
                if thisBlock.position.x = blockMaxX{
                    thisBlock.position.x -= CGFloat(self.groundSpeed)
                } else {
                    thisBlock.position.x = self.origBlockPositionX
                    blockStatus.isRunning = false
                    self.score++
                    if ((self.score % 5) == 0) {
                        self.groundSpeed++
                    }
                    self.scoreText.text = String(self.score)
                }
            } else {
                blockStatus.currentInterval++
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: childNodeWithName returns an SKNode, and SKNode doesn't have a property named position. Is thisBlock an SKSpriteNode?

Answer (score 0):

`childNodeWithName()` does return an optional `SKNode?` which you have to unwrap to use. I don't know why `var thisBlock = self.childNodeWithName(block)!` didn't solve your issue.  I would recommend using *optional binding* (`if let`) syntax:

```
if let thisBlock = self.childNodeWithName(block) {
    if blockStatus.shouldRunBlock() {
        blockStatus.timeGapForNextRun = random()
        blockStatus.currentInterval = 0
        blockStatus.isRunning = true
    }

    if blockStatus.isRunning {
        ... rest of your code
}
```

This has the added advantage of not crashing if there are no children nodes.  It just won't enter the block.